# Ajax+JSP + Oracle retrieve result table according to search like jquery : onKeyUp( )

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle, jsp

My Complete detailed query is in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari007/rwn438nt/)**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="id"  placeholder="Seach Member By ID"> &nbsp;

 <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Seach Member By Name"> &nbsp;

   <input type="text" name="dept" placeholder="Seach Member By Registration">
</form>
```

i need to show search filter among user searched type of selected Item only. For Example if usertypes in ID Field table should filter and Display by ID value of result only. For Example else if user types in Name Field or registration field table should filter and Display by Names value of result only

For Example if user types in 3rd Field table should filter by it's value of result only

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr> 
            <th>Student ID </<th>
             <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Student Department </th>
            <th>Registration Number</th> 
            <th>Details Link</th> 
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3> 501   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> HARI   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> CSE   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> Y32K11   </h3></td>
                 <td><input type=button value="Click here"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3> 5005   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> GOPI   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> ECE   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> Y32K15   </h3></td>
                 <td><input type=button value="Click here"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3> 5002   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> JAYA   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> CIVIL   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> Y32K18   </h3></td>
                 <td><input type=button value="Click here"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3> 5009   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> MANI   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> MECH   </h3></td>
                <td><h3> Y32K99   </h3></td>
                <td><input type=button value="Click here"/></td>
            </tr>                  
   </table>
```

i tried jquery + Ajax + JDBC (thin) + JSP(netbeans) + Oracle DB (11g ). Up to now i came to the way of populating Table ROW details by using dropdown of any one field with Ajax jQuery Oracle DB resultset

Initially div or table area should be hidde.  After entering Very First key in any Field, result of that character related should Display below search (like dynamically

Comment: You can use DATATABLE for this

Comment: it's a sample bro ... i did all amount of back end ... i just need auto suggestion or auto pop up table type of process